# Wide gap in my resume as a Java developer. What are must-have skills required to get hired those days?

Tags: java, self-improvement

For some legal reasons I haven't worked for anybody for the last 12 years. I am a java web developer or at least I am thinking so. For this period I have been working on my project- some sort of business network - and I did few small jobs, so right now I feel I am far behind in terms of my skills and the skills needed today.

I lingered too long on Struts and Hibernate and thought that could the job for my project. I need to get a job, right now, so I am spending most of my time brushing my skills.

My question is: What are the current necessary skills that could convince employers to hire me regardless of my past employment or the lack of it.

Right now I am on  AspectJ, IoC and Spring

Answer (score 4):

- Hibernate is still very much relevant, though more as the leading implementation of the JPA standard.
- Struts is well past its prime. But there's still a ton of legacy code using it that needs maintaining.
- AOP never gained much commercial traction, so for resume polishing, AspectJ is a waste of time
- Spring is definitely big, everyone uses Dependency Injection these days, either Spring or Java EE, with the CDI standard creating a common ground.
- Since EJB version 3, Java EE (formerly J2EE) is regaining a lot of popularity.
- Learning one (or preferably a few) web framework other than Struts would be very important. Could be Spring MVC, could be JSF, Apache Wicket or Play.
- When you do web frontends, knowledge of JavaScript and JQuery is a must these days.
- Automated testing using JUnit and assorted libraries, including some mocking framework shows that you care about quality.
- Build automation using Ant or Maven, and Jenkins is needed in any truly professional environment.

But the size of you skillset bullet list doesn't matter when you can't convince prospective employers that you actually have experience with those technologies. They probably get 20 resumes a day from desparate people who outright lie in their resumes. The best thing you can probably do is build stuff you can actually put on the web to demonstrate your knowledge of these technologies.